# attach and detach a fragment from another

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have two Fragments. I want to update Fragment #2 in the background from Fragment #1.

Fragment #2 is my Favorite list Fragment... And in my Fragment #1, I get some data with JSON and populate into a listview. Now I have to refresh Fragment #2 to have my new favorited item. So I decided to reload Fragment #2 when the user clicks on a bookmark icon from Fragment #1.

I tried this inside Fragment #1:

```
Fragment frg = null;
frg = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Fragment#2.myTag);
final FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

But `frg` is returning `null`...

How can I achieve this!?

Comment: Are you sure frg is not null?

Comment: can u plz explain your problem..?i didn't get it..!

Comment: @S.R. "Now I checked, it is null" Did you mean NOT null? Because if it's null it means your fragment is not found.